# jQuery.hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a surprisingly simple piece of jQuery code that doesn't work as expected.

I want to change the class of a div when I hover over it and restore the class back when the mouse is out of the area of the div. Here's my code.

```
function WireHandlers()
{
    SetBannerHoverImage();
}

function SetBannerHoverImage()
{
    $("#banner").hover( OnBannerHover. OnBannerOut );
}

function OnBannerHover()
{
    $("#banner").removeClass("grayGradiant");
    $("#banner").addClass("redGradiant");
}

function OnBannerOut()
{
    $("#banner").removeClass("redGradiant");
    $("#banner").addClass("grayGradiant");
}

$(document).ready( function() { WireHandlers(); } );
```

The document.ready does call `WireHandlers`, which does call `SetBannerHoverImage`, which does successfully call the `$(selector).hover()` method.

However, when I hover over the div, the `OnBannerHover` and `OnBannerOut` listeners are not called.

**PS:** It might be important to note that inside the div covering 100% of its area is a table.

Comment: Did you mean `( OnBannerHover, OnBannerOut );`?

Comment: Is there any reason for making things complex using unnecessary functions for one `hover` event only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the example from api.jquery.com you need to seperate your handler with a comma:

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

So try:

```
$("#banner").hover( OnBannerHover, OnBannerOut );
```

Comment: Damn the typo. Thank you. :-) 6 more minutes before I can mark this answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
$("#banner").hover(
function(){
$(this).removeClass('red').addClass('grey');
},
function(){
$(this).removeClass('grey').addClass('red');
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a typo

```
$("#banner").hover( OnBannerHover. OnBannerOut );
```

then it should be

```
$("#banner").hover( OnBannerHover, OnBannerOut );
```

Alternatively, you can use (`hover` is just a shorthand of these)

```
$("#banner").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("grayGradiant").addClass("redGradiant");
})
.on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("redGradiant").addClass("grayGradiant");
});
```